# Finding a trigonometric function for a problem

Tags: trigonometry

The question:
At Dolphin Bay the depth of the water at the end of the jetty is 6 metres at high and 4 metres at low tide. High tide occurs at 11am and low tide occurs at 5pm.

a). Using the information given find a trigonometric function which models the depth of the water at the end of the jetty.

b. Find the depth of the water at 12:30pm.

c). A boat moored at the end of the jetty needs to leave the Bay before the depth of the water falls to 4 metres. At what time after the 11am high tide will the depth of the water be 4 metres?

d). Find the next time after low tide when the depth of the water will again be 4 metres.

Comment: Define your time variable **specifically**:  What are the units?  What time does $t = 0$ refer to?  (These are arbitrary choices, but *write down* your choices).

Comment: What is the *equilibrium* height of the water?  The sinusoidal function will fluctuate above and below this height.  Once you know this height, you should be able to determine the *amplitude* of the fluctuations.

Comment: What is the *period* (one complete cycle) of the tides?  How do you modify a standard sinusoidal function (with period $2\pi$) to have the correct period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of representing the trigonometric function which models the **depth of the water**  is:
$$5-Asin(2\pi {t\over T})$$
**Where:**
$t=0$ is considered to be 2 pm
$A=1$  -The Amplitude
$T=12$-The time period
**Hence**
$$D(t)=5-sin({{\pi t}\over 6})$$